# MSSQL LocalDb has blue question mark icon in SSMS, can't update database with EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ssms, localdb

I am trying to setup a new localdb and update using EF Core. I can connect to the server fine and create databases, however it has a blue question mark icon instead of a green checkmark.

[image]

Attempting to run update-database also returns an error that seems to be from the same issue

[image]

This is the connection string I am using:`services.AddDbContext<ScDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Database=mydb; Trusted_Connection=True;"));`

Comment: Have a look at this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci

Answer (score 0):

The '?' is simply that your current userid is unable to get access the view the services on the database server. This can be because there is a firewall blocking you, because your userid has no permissions on the server or WMI services are not running on the server.

All the '?' means is that SSMS is unable to tell you the state of the services, nor can you change the state.

I Do not think this is connected to your issue.